# How to allow a view to listen to selection of other views?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-gmf

I'm developing a plugin with EMF and GMF. 
It has two views and I want that when one element is selected in the first one the second is refreshed.

Actually I used this command:

```
getViewSite().getPage().addSelectionListener(this);
```

But it allows me to listen only the selections in the editor.

How can I fix it?
And how can I ensure that the view is refreshed when the plugin is loaded?
Currently when I start the plugin it is empty and it is refreshed as soon as I click on the editor.

Thanks,
Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [use Selection Service](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-WorkbenchSelections/article.html):

```
getViewSite().getWorkbenchWindow().getSelectionService().addSelectionListener(this)
```

or

```
getViewSite().getWorkbenchWindow().getSelectionService().addSelectionListener(partId, this)
```

to listen for selection changes in a specific view/editor.

Comment: I suppose that in the second method partId is the view that I want to observ, right?

Comment: Hi, I finally had the time for testing you hint. It doesn't work.  Do I have to add the view that I'm listening as a selection provider? Currently I do it in that way: `getSite().setSelectionProvider(viewer); where `viewer` is the `tableViewer`

Comment: @lucaghera: "Do I have to add the view that I'm listening as a selection provider?" Yes, and in the way you give.

Comment: mmm...and so why it does't work? I used the method you suggested in this way : `getViewSite().getWorkbenchWindow().getSelectionService().addSelectionListener(InstanceView.ID, this);`

Comment: Actually it works. It was a old control that I didn't remove. The fine thing is that it works without using the method you suggested. Indeed it is enough the method I proposed in the question :D
Thanks for the time you give me!